# MenuButton won't open menu

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

I am baffled as to why my qx.ui.form.MenuButton won't open the menu I'm applying to it. Can anyone tell me the idiotic error I must be making?

```
qx.Class.define("app.ui.files.FilesListPanel", {
    extend: qx.ui.container.Composite,

    construct: function() {
        this.base(arguments);
        this.setWidth(350);

        var datasetsMenu = new qx.ui.menu.Menu();
        datasetsMenu.add(new qx.ui.menu.Button("Test 1"));
        datasetsMenu.add(new qx.ui.menu.Button("Test 2"));

        var datasetsMenuButton = new qx.ui.form.MenuButton("Select dataset", null, datasetsMenu);

        this._list = new qx.ui.form.List();

        this.setLayout(new qx.ui.layout.VBox());
        this.add(datasetsMenuButton);
        this.add(this._list, {flex: 1});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work as expected in the playground, in Chrome 66 on Linux. Please paste the following code in place of the default example at http://playground.qooxdoo.org:

```
qx.Class.define("app.ui.files.FilesListPanel", {
  extend: qx.ui.container.Composite,

  construct: function() {
    this.base(arguments);
    this.setWidth(350);

    var datasetsMenu = new qx.ui.menu.Menu();
    datasetsMenu.add(new qx.ui.menu.Button("Test 1"));
    datasetsMenu.add(new qx.ui.menu.Button("Test 2"));

    var datasetsMenuButton = new qx.ui.form.MenuButton("Select dataset", null, datasetsMenu);

    this._list = new qx.ui.form.List();

    this.setLayout(new qx.ui.layout.VBox());
    this.add(datasetsMenuButton);
    this.add(this._list, {flex: 1});
  }
});

var flp = new app.ui.files.FilesListPanel();
this.getRoot().add(flp, { edge : 10 });
```

When I click the button, it shows two menu items, as expected. If it does not work like that for you, please specify what operating system and version you're running, and which browser and version... or if I'm misunderstanding your needs, please explain what behavior different than what I described you are expecting.

Comment: Ya, I see that it works in the playground as I would expect--when I press the "Select dataset" menu button, I get a drop-down with two items ("Test 1" and "Test 2"). In the context of my own application, however, the button doesn't show the two items at all.

Comment: I'd suggest stripping down your application to the bare minimum that contains the FilesListPanel but exhibits the problem. If you can produce a playground example that shows the problem, we should be able to help you.